# Problem recording prometheus metrics from services built on micronaut/netty v3.4.1

Tags: prometheus, netty, micronaut

The infrastructure I'm deploying into employs a prometheus metric scraping proxy that connects to prometheus endpoints using a socket level client instead of an HTTP client.

My micronaut/jetty services are fine when deploying into this infrastructure, but micronaut/netty services don't get metrics picked up.  Digging into the problem a bit, if I try to connect the the prometheus endpoint of a micronaut/netty service when it's running locally or deployed with a socket level client (ex. nc), I get HTTP 401.  But if I repeat the test using an HTTP client (ex. curl) passing the same header data, I get metrics as expected.

Has anyone seen this or similar behavior from micronaut/netty HTTP endpoints and most importantly know of a workaround?  I don't like my chances of convincing my infrastructure vendor to rewrite their scraping proxy to use an HTTP client in a reasonable amount of time.

Comment: Your problem is unclear. HTTP is a protocol that runs on (historically) TCP. (TCP/)IP sockets are a common way that 2 computers network. When you e.g. browse or `curl` Prometheus endpoints, you're using HTP (on TCP). If your infrastructure vendor provides IP sockets, then you can put an HTTP client (e.g. browser) on one end and, if an HTTP server like Prometheus is on the other end, you'll be talking HTTP. If you want to use `nc`, you'll need to manually construct the HTTP messages.

Comment: An HTTP 401 is unauthorized suggesting that you're reaching the server but not providing it with the authentication credentials (perhaps in an `Authorization` header) that it expects.